# Make command create a.file but not create application file

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

im trying to compile the next code https://github.com/srivathsanmurali/domsetLibrary
and when i run `cmake ..` and `make` i get a.file and the application file is missing.
there is any idea why ?

```
   total 2300
drwxr-xr-x 3 dorc23 dorc23    4096 Dec 23 22:48 ./

drwxr-xr-x 6 dorc23 root      4096 Dec 23 22:34 ../

-rw-r--r-- 1 dorc23 dorc23   12892 Dec 23 22:47 CMakeCache.txt

drwxr-xr-x 5 dorc23 dorc23    4096 Dec 23 23:00 CMakeFiles/

-rw-r--r-- 1 dorc23 dorc23    1544 Dec 23 22:47 cmake_install.cmake

**-rw-r--r-- 1 dorc23 dorc23 2310720 Dec 23 22:48 libdomset.a** 

-rw-r--r-- 1 dorc23 dorc23    4872 Dec 23 22:47 Makefile
```

Comment: It looks like you are only build a library. Why should there be an executable?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There is only a library provided by this source code repository, there is no application file that should be generated. The `libdomset.a` library is the *only* file that should be built, according to the CMake. What leads you to believe there is an application file as well?

Comment: in the Makefile the is file that call domset he needs to be the exe file @squareskittles    # Build rule for target.
domset: cmake_check_build_system
 $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 domset
.PHONY : domset

Comment: The Makefile here shouldn't contain an executable. You have to create the executable yourself, then link that executable to `libdomset.a`.

Comment: maybe im wrong.. but any way how can i make application file by myself?

Comment: you can give me some example or someting ? i never do it before @squareskittles

Comment: @דורכהן Take a look at the GitHub page under "usage". They show an example program there.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline 
i see the program under "Usage" , how i make the link with the library ?

Comment: i success to create excitable file ..thanks all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a static library; that's what the .a file is. You need to write a separate program, include the header file(s), and link with this library.

Comment: i see the program under "Usage" , how i make the link with the library ?